# Amazon Alexa no output from Lambda Function

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am starting with Alexa. I have setup a basic Lambda function and a custom skill set.

[image]

When I test the lambda function, it produces the correct output

[image]

but when I test the skill from the Test Skill section, it does not receive any output from the lambda function.

[image]

What could be the reason?

Comment: could you show us the lambda code? There could be a plethora of reasons for this and most of them will have to do with the actual code in the lambda function.

Comment: You have say Alexa, open "invocation name". That's how you invoke your skill.

Comment: Did you specify the end points correctly? Both in your skill and in your lambda function. And could you please expand the `Details` of the log in the Execution Result. Even if you're not returning anything, but there is no error in the execution of the lambda, the lambda will show successful execution, although the result may not be fit for Alexa skill.